# How do you open the control center from Linux Mint Cinammon Desktop terminal?

Tags: terminal, linux-mint

How do you open the control center from Linux Mint Cinammon Desktop terminal?

Also, is it just shooter's preference for which file management is best? I don't have a problem with Nemo so far but if there's better out there, any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some options, tested in Mint 20.

1. In a terminal, type `cinnamon-settings`
2. `ALT+F2` and type `cinnamon-settings`
3. Click the *Menu*, click the *System Settings* icon on the left in the quick options.
4. *Windows* key then type *System Settings* (the cursor should be focused on the search box so typing works).

**Older answer, not valid since Mint 20**

I'm not 100% sure what you mean by "control center". If you mean the "System Settings", personally one of the quickest ways is:

1. Right mouse click on the desktop.
2. Select *Change Desktop Background* (opens that setting box).
3. Select the *arrow* in the top left (opens the System Settings).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, this is my first OS I'm trying to learn the "guts" of so I'm new to the terminology. I did mean System Settings as you said. However, is there a way to pull this up from the terminal? If not, I totally get it but I'm trying to see if I can run as much as I can from the terminal. Thank you for the help!

Comment: See edited update to answer.

Answer (score 0):

`cinnamon-settings` will show some settings, `cinnamon-control-center` will show a bunch of other settings. No idea [why the settings aren't all in one place](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=1941928#p1941928).